# What is decoherence important for?

Tags: decoherence

Decoherence has several important applications or is important in not only one way. There is the theoretical (and now also practical) interest in the quantum-to-classical transition. There is it's relevance to quantum computing, where decoherence is a source of error that needs to be controlled. There also is the rather logical importance of it for every experiment in the lab, where ideal conditions are necessary for it's conduction. I can also see an importance for the philosophy (of physics) regarding the interpretation of quantum physics.

Apart from all this, is there any aspect (which decoherence has an important practical effect on) or application (of decoherence) I have missed?

Comment: This question may work better if you can ask something with a more well-defined answer. You're asking for a list of applications of a concept, and such questions do not have well defined correct answers.

Comment: Decoherence is the transfer of energy between a quantum system and its environment. It is hard to see what special philosophical consequences this should have for physics, given that all of physics is about the transfer of energy. It is also questionable to state that we need ideal conditions in laboratory experiments. Even if that phrase made any sense in general, the suppression of decoherence would certainly be the last thing that an experimentalist could use. Indeed, all of our classical observables require open systems that facilitate energy loss to the environment.